# Analyze BIg O relation between weird math expressions (logN)^logN and n/logN

Tags: math, big-o, theory

(logN)^logN and n/logN 
what is the Big O relation between these two? and how to derive a proof the relation?

Answer (score 2):

One initial observation you can make is that if you take the log of both of these expressions, you get the following:

> log ((log n)<sup>log n</sup>) = log n log log n
>
> log (n / log n) = log n - log log n

Notice that the first of these terms grows faster than the second, so we'd expect to get that n / log n = O((log n)<sup>log n</sup>).

To prove this, we can take the limit of the ratio of these expressions as n tends toward infinity.  If we get 0, then we're done.  I'll leave this as a proverbial exercise to the reader. :-)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `x = log n`. If the logarithm is in base `a`, you have `n = a^x`. Now,

```
(log n)^(log n) = x^x
n / log n       = a^x / x
```

When `x > a` and `a > 1` you have x<sup>x</sup> > a<sup>x</sup>.

On the other hand, when `x > 1`, a<sup>x</sup> > a<sup>x</sup> / x.

Combining these two, you get x<sup>x</sup> > a<sup>x</sup> / x. If you now substitute back,

```
(log n)^(log n) > n / log n        when log n > a, i.e. when n > a^a
```

This proves that n/log n is in O((log n)<sup>log n</sup>).